# Please check these proofs for sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I would appreciate the insight again for a couple of proofs since I'm learning.  These are homework problems in so much as they are problems from the textbook.  They are not required by my professor.  I'm doing a little extra through spring break.

The objective was to prove the statement or provide counter examples.  I'd like to have my work critiqued since I've got to refine my abilities for proofs.

The following applies to both problems: Let $A, B, C$ be sets.

### Problem 1

Prove: $A \oplus B = A \oplus C \Rightarrow B = C$.

My objective is to is to show that $B \subseteq C$ and $C \subseteq B$.

Proof:
Case 1:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{let}\, x \in B \mid x \in A \oplus B \\
\text{so,}\, x \in B \, \text{and} \, x \notin A \text{, by definition} \\
\text{since,}\, A \oplus B = A \oplus C, x \in C \,\square
\end{align}
$$

Case 2:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{let}\, x \in C \mid x \in A \oplus C \\
\text{so,}\, x \in C \, \text{and} \, x \notin A \text{, by definition} \\
\text{since,}\, A \oplus C = A \oplus B, x \in B \,\square
\end{align}
$$

### Problem 2

Prove: $A \times B = A \times C \Rightarrow B = C$.
A similar problem and I must show that $B \subseteq C$ and $C \subseteq B$.

Proof:
Case 1:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{let} (a,b) \in A \times B\, \text{and}\, (a,c) \in A \times C \\
\text{since}\, A \times B = A \times C \text{,}\, \forall (a,b)\text{,} (a,b) = (a,c) \\
\text{so,}\, a = a\, \text{and}\, b=c \\
\text{thus}\, \forall b \in B, b \in C\,\square
\end{align}
$$

Case 2:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{let} (a,c) \in A \times C\, \text{and}\, (a,b) \in A \times B \\
\text{since}\, A \times C = A \times B \text{,}\, \forall (a,c)\text{,} (a,c) = (a,b) \\
\text{so,}\, a = a\, \text{and}\, c=b \\
\text{thus}\, \forall c \in C, c \in B\,\square
\end{align}
$$

I do appreciate the critique.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Your problem $2$ is right. However, what definition of $\otimes$ are you using?

Comment: $\oplus$ is associative, $A\oplus A=\varnothing$ and $C\oplus \varnothing =C$ for any $C$. By adding $A$ on the left to $A\oplus C=A\oplus B$ you get what you want.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar $\oplus$ is defined as the symmetric difference between sets.  $A \oplus B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'm having a bit of trouble visualizing how this works.  We haven't covered addition of sets.  I see the two operations you've done for symmetric difference.  Is this what you mean: $A \oplus A \oplus C = A \oplus A \oplus B \rightarrow C = B$?

Comment: @AndrewFalanga Yes. You have addition and inverses. Much like $a+b=a+c\implies b=c$ by adding $-a$ to both sides.

Comment: In problem 2 you need to assume $A\ne\emptyset$. Since $\emptyset\times B=\emptyset\times C$ is true for any $B$, $C$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your solution to Problem $2$ is correct.

I believe that your solution to Problem $1$ is correct, but (as Pedro Tamaroff pointed out) it's not the "easiest" proof.  A more straightforward proof is to say:

> Let $A,\;B,\;C$ be sets, and $A\oplus B = A\oplus C$.  Adding $A$ on the left gives:
>   $$A\oplus (A \oplus B) = A\oplus(A\oplus C)$$
>   $$(A\oplus A) \oplus B = (A\oplus A)\oplus C \tag{$\oplus$ is associative}$$ 
>   $$\emptyset \oplus B = \emptyset \oplus C \tag{$A \oplus A = \emptyset$ for all $A$}$$
>   $$B = C \tag{$\emptyset \oplus A = A \oplus \emptyset = A$ for all $A$}$$

Comment: I like this proof.  That's great.  For the class, we didn't spend much time with the $\oplus$ and my prof would have wanted me to demonstrate that it's associative (i.e. prove it).  I know this because of a conversation I had with him about one of the tests.